# Keycloak config ignore env variables

Tags: keycloak

Hi I try to start an standalone keycloak Server within a Docker container.

I set an "env" variable for production, local oder test for that the server connects to the correct MySQL DB.

But upon start up on AWS it seems to ignore the env vars. Localy Dockermachine works fine.

Here is the config setup:

in standalone.xml:

```
...for (empty) local
<datasource jndi-name="java:/jboss/datasources/KeycloakMysqlDS-default" pool-name="KeycloakMysqlDS-default" enabled="true">
...for production
<datasource jndi-name="java:/jboss/datasources/KeycloakMysqlDS-production" pool-name="KeycloakMysqlDS-production" enabled="true">
...
<provider name="default" enabled="true">
  <properties>
    <property name="dataSource" value="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakMysqlDS-${env.env}"/>
....
```

The 'env' var is verified set to "production" on AWS and empty on local and also reacts in local dockermachine changes.

Just on starting on the AWS dockermachine it uses the default instead of the {env.env} var.

Anyone saw the behaviour before? Or have an idea how to correct it?

Thanks in advance

Gregor

UPDATE:
Well the error does not happen on startup.
It happens several minutes afterwards:

```
...
WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (JCA PoolFiller) IJ000610: Unable to fill pool: java:/jboss/datasources/KeycloakMysqlDS-default: ... Connection refused.
...
```

So it probably not a problem with the env var. 
Instead Keycloak seems to try to open connection to setted datasource... is it true?

Comment: Have you tried with `ENV`? Anyway, I don't think calling the variable `env` might be a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

Completley another problem...

Keycloak bid to another IP by default. Had to set the ip to 0.0.0.0 to work inside a Docker container.

in configuration.xml...

```
  <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/>
            <!--<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>-->
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
            <!--<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>-->
        </interface>
    </interfaces>
```